# showing that the Diophantine $3x^2+2=y^2+6z^3$ equation has no solutions

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

I'd really love your help with showing that the Diophantine $3x^2+2=y^2+6z^3$ equation has no solutions.

I know that Diophantine equation of the form $ax+by+cz=d$ iff $\gcd(a,b,c)  | d$, but how do I deal with the squares?

Any hints? suggestions?

Thanks!

Comment: mod 3! ${}{}{}{}{}$

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If $(x,y,z)$ is a solution, then looking modulo $3$ you should have
$$y^2\equiv2\pmod3$$

It is then easy to see that there is no integer satisfying this equation.

Comment: Thank you, How can I prove that the solution of $y= \sqrt{3k+2}$ for every $k\in\mathbb{Z}$ is not an integer?

Comment: @Jozef if $y\equiv0\pmod3$, $y^2\equiv0\pmod3$.  Otherwise, $y^2\equiv1\pmod3$ by Fermat's Little Theorem.

Comment: if $y=0 [3]$, then $y^2=0 [3]$, and if $y=1$ or $2[3]$, then $y^2=1[3]$....